# Проблема с подключением JavaFX в intellij IDEA

Tags: java, linux, javafx, gui

*Добрый день,*


Я новичок в программирование, дошёл до изучения JavaFX. 
Но возникли некоторые проблемы.
**IDEA не видит** не пакетов, не классов, не методов JavaFX.
По совместительству являюсь пользователем Ubuntu, операцию по установки в linux Java FX уже выполнил

> sudo apt-get install openjfx

JDK естественно установлена, пробовал создавать проект как через Java, так и через JavaFX -- бесполезно. Скриншот прилагается


*Заранее спасибо*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. поставьте JDK 8 и не парьтесь. 2. Если все таки хотите париться, то вам нужен maven, что бы в нем подключить `javafx` ибо он идет как отдельная зависимость.

Answer (score 2):

*0. установи OpenJDK. Реально меньше проблем будет*

1. установи **JavaFX**: https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/
2. в *Idea*  в свой проект добавь внешнюю библиотеку:
   Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S: Project Settings -> Libraries -> **+** -> {выбираешь *install/pass/to/JavaFX/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib*}
3. обязательно добавляешь **VM Option**:
   Run -> Edit Configurations -> Application -> {YourApp}:

Configuration -> VM options: **--module-path ${PATH_TO_FX} --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.base**

где **${PATH_TO_FX}** - это твой путь к библиотеке JavaFX (*install/pass/to/JavaFX/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib*)

либо прописываешь в **Path Variables**:
File -> Setings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Path Variables -> **+**:
Name = PATH_TO_FX, Value = install/pass/to/JavaFX/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib

4. можно еще установить **SceneBuilder**: https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/ , но это - по желанию

Answer (score 1):

При использовании Maven:

Добавить в pom.xml:

```
<build>
      <plugins>
            <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                  <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>0.0.3</version>
                  <configuration>
                         <mainClass>com.example.App</mainClass>
                  </configuration>
             </plugin>
       </plugins>
</build>
```

и

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

`com.example.App` - класс, который `extends Application`

Answer (score 0):

Проще действительно использовать maven или gradle, как указали в комментарии.

Пускай вы новичек, потратьте немного времени на их изучение - и это значительно упростит дальнейшее обучение и разработку. С помощью них не нужно устанавливать javaFX или другие зависимости отдельно, всё делается в конфигурационном файле в пару строк.

maven попроще, а gradle посложнее, но возможностей намного больше (для javafx с gradle используйте не просто зависимости, а плагины, гуглите "javafx gradle plugin")

А в данном случае, насколько я помню разработку без чудесных maven/gradle, нужно открыть настройки проекта (ctrl-alt-shift-s) и в разделе libraries добавить установленный javafx

Answer (score 0):

Если все таки решите делать через maven, то [вот](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_tdK8zWr_w&index=5&list=LLqC6zt9k1hxnAG6wwh99MoQ&t=0s) отличное руководство по запуску. Если не хотите использовать maven, то можно скачать библиотеку javaFX [отсюда](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/), а затем в подключить ее в структуре проекта intellij idea (не помню как точно, но визуально там все понятно).

Answer (score 0):

Есть два варианта:
1) использовать maven и не париться
2) Качать openJFX (качать openJFX https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/) и читать хелп https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx

Я бы лучше посоветовал разобраться с maven, благо ссылку на урок вам дали.

Если очень коротко:
Idea-File-New-Project-Maven(выбираем JDK и снимаем галку с архитипа)-
GroupID: javaFX, ArtifactID: sample
Next - Finish.

Когда откроется проект нужно в файл POM.xml добавить

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
<artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>8.8.3</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

IDEA сама скачает зависимости.
Ну а дальше вы вроде знаете

Answer (score 0):

---

План "А" - Указать библиотеку в Run

---

шаг#1:

```
    Project Srtucture --> Modules --> 

Path 
 
   (*) Inherit project compile output path
   ( ) Use module compile output path

Dependencies 

   |+| --> 2 Library --> Java --> ВЬІБРАТЬ РАСПОЛОЖЕНИЕ /lib
```

---

шаг#2:

```
    Run --> Edit Configuration --> 
    VM options:
```

КОПИРОВАТЬ И ВСТАВИТЬ В ПОЛЕ СЛЕДУЮЩЕЕ:

---

```
--module-path {ВЬІБРАТЬ РАСПОЛОЖЕНИЕ /lib} --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

---

```
      |OK||   ||Apply|
```

---

План "Б" - Указать модуль с библиотекой в Run

---

шаг#1:

```
  Project Srtucture --> Modules --> 

Path 
 ( ) Inherit project compile output path
 (*) Use module compile output path

Dependencies
 |+| --> 2 Library --> Java --> ВЬІБРАТЬ РАСПОЛОЖЕНИЕ FX lib
```

---

шаг#2:

```
     File --> Settings --> Path Variables --> |+|
```

ВСТАВИТЬ -->    PATH_TO_FIX   В ПОЛЕ Name:

```
    Add Variables 
Name:      PATH_TO_FX                 
Value:   ВЬІБРАТЬ РАСПОЛОЖЕНИЕ /lib 
                 |OK||   |
```

---

шаг#3:

```
  Run --> Edit Configuration --> VM options:
```

КОПИРОВАТЬ И ВСТАВИТЬ В ПОЛЕ СЛЕДУЮЩЕЕ:

---

```
--module-path $PATH_TO_FX$ --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

---

***РАЗНИЦА СИМВОЛОВ:

$  -  $Linux$ -  $PATH_TO_FIX$
% - %Windows% -  %PATH_TO_FIX%

МЬІШЬ правая клавиша - IDEA заполнит сама ВЬІБРАНЬІЙ МОДУЛЬ

---

```
       |OK||   ||Apply|
```

---

---

PS. ДЛЯ ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЯ ОШИБОК

---

ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ:

---

```
          Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V
          ТОЛЬКО ОДНУ ВЕРСИЮ БИБЛИОТЕКИ FX
```

---

НЕ СМЕШИВАТЬ:

---

```
          КОМПОНЕНТЬІ РАЗНЬІХ ВЕРСИЙ БИБЛИОТЕК FX
```

---